# Image not displaying correctly when applying round CSS-border and opacity-effect

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find an already existing question that answers the following problem:

I have added a 300 x 300 Pixel squared png-image of a circle to my website. I am using Zurb's Foundation 5.0.2 as a CSS Grid-basis.

I would like to create a CSS-border around the circle and add an opacity-effect so that
the image is only fully visible when you hover over it with your mouse. The surrounding CSS-border and background should not be affected by this hovering-effect. Please have a look at the links to see the images.

This is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="large-4 columns" id="border">

            <div id="foto"><img src="/img/test.png" alt="Portrait" width="300" height="300"></div>

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #border #foto {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 300px;
        height:300px;
        background: #1ABC9C;
        border: 15px solid #34495E; 

}  

#foto:hover {
        opacity: 1.0;        
}



#foto {
        opacity:0.5;        
}
```

This code correctly displays the border around the circle, but applies the hovering-effect to both, border and image:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2r989g7d14exyfr/screenshot1.png

When I modify the CSS in the following way, it correctly applies the hover-effect only to the picture, but reduces the image size and doesn't display it centered any longer:

```
#border {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    background: #1ABC9C;
    border: 15px solid #34495E;
```

}

https://www.dropbox.com/s/izmohri8bxkngp6/screenshot2.png?m=

Could you please advise me how to display the image correctly and apply the hover-effect as intended?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/u9LrK/1/

```
#foto, #foto img {
    background: #1ABC9C;
    border-radius:50%;
}
#foto {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 15px solid #34495E; 
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
#foto:hover img {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `border` from `#border #foto` and add `overflow:hidden` to it.

Write:

```
#foto:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#foto {
    opacity:0.5;
}
#border {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    background: #1ABC9C;
    border: 15px solid #34495E;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CbxwG/2)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using exactly your Fiddle-code, unfortunately, it still does not display the picture correctly:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5h8zegce94ibtt/screenshot3.png

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow:hidden to your border & foto div(s).

```
#border #foto {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    background: #1ABC9C;
    border: 15px solid #34495E; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ufdM7/